# Replace Burner ignitor Maytag gas range

Tags: repair, gas, range

How to access the ignitor of 1 burner on Maytag gas oven/Range model MGR5775QDQ. Does the burner unscrew from the top to remove it, or must it be removed from the bottom.

Comment: Please post a photo or two

Answer (score 0):

There are different types.  Some you can remove the burner from above, and the igniter is attached to the burner.  Others have the igniter attached to the stove deck, which usually just flips up like the hood of a car (you do need to remove any grates first!).  Only you can say which yours is, but based on a Google search, my guess would be the former.

YMMV on burner removal, depending how crudded up it is from food, or rusty the fasteners are (water *is* a byproduct of combustion).